# set text vertical position when text is horizontal center (text-aling: center)

Tags: html, css

I have seen many questions and answer how to centre a text vertical and horizontal. My question is how do I change the vertical position of text when its centre horizontal? I don't want to centre it vertical, maybe just few pixels below. I tried top: xx%; doesn't work. what else am I missing?

CSS

```
p{
    color: #7C7C7C;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: `My question is how do I change the vertical position of text when its center horizontal? I don't want to center it vertical`. You mean you want to center it horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for example margin-top: ??px;

Comment: Yes but I have several text line that I would like to be center horizontal and one underneath the other without that much space apart. if I use margin-top I will set the first line to the place I want for example margin-top 100px, but the next line will be 100px apart from the first line.

Comment: Never mind fixed it :), just had to add a div with the margin-top ??px to all the text as a group

Comment: for text in div container you can use padding-top too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `div` to wrap your text.

```html
<div style="background: green; width 150px; height: 60px; text-align:center">
  <p>Abcd
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Align in center using translateY property as shown in the below snippets

```html
  <head>
    <style>
      p{
        text-align:center;
        transform:translateY(50vh);
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Center</p>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS top property will move the element if you use position relative.  Alternatively, you can use padding-top or margin-top.

```
p {
  position:relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

or

```
p {
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

[box model reference for padding and margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) and
[position reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control)

Comment: But that wont center the text horizontal. I have few lines of text that i want it to be center horizontal and moved verticaly a bit.